# Name server does not have direct parent zone information?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I'm curious about this error that comes up in an online DNS report, and unable to find information about how I might fix it:

```
Direct Parent Check:    The Parent DNS Server [ns1.xxxxxxx.org.uk] does not have information for your direct parent zone org.uk. This is OK but can be confusing.
```

I control the DNS server in question (running bind9 on Debian 11). Is this a misconfiguration of some kind?

Comment: It's very hard to follow what that message might be actually saying the way it is obfuscated as well as out of context.

Comment: How would you suggest clarifying it? The context is from a DNS check at https://network-tools.webwiz.net/dns-report.htm if that helps.

Comment: The easiest way of clarifying it would be to name the domain where you get this message, such that someone else than you can look at what the actual situation is. Other than that, I think this is most likely to be answered by either someone who happens to already know what this exact phrasing in this tool refers to (not very clear) or by you.